# How to automatically kill celery workers when the queue they listen on gets empty?

Tags: python, process, celery, worker

Is there any "clean" way of killing the worker processes once the queue they've been listening to gets empty?

The idea is that I don't need to have the workers continuously listening to the queue, if they don't have any work to do. I tried the autoscale option, but from my experience, even if I set the lower threshold to 0, the worker doesn't die.

In my case I need to download 1000 files from somewhere, using celery. So I put 1000 tasks in the queue, but that's all the work that I want this batch of workers to do. It would be ideal if they could somehow die after they all finished downloading all the files, and not idle there until I remember to kill the processes manually.

I couldn't find any suggestion of how to do this from within celery.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the very nice [Rq simple job queue system](http://python-rq.org/), you'd run it in "burst mode."  The worker will start up, start processing all jobs in the queues, and die.  To process more jobs, we start the worker again every minute or so using Cron.

For Celery, we can do the equivalent by using two separate Cron jobs:

> */2 * * * * celery -A proj worker -l info

This starts Celery every even minute.

> 1-59/2 * * * * ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' |
>   xargs kill

On odd minutes, [stop](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#stopping-the-worker) the Celery worker.  Fortunately for us: "When shutdown is initiated the worker will finish all currently executing tasks before it actually terminates".

The combination of the above means Celery only runs about 50% of the time. With a bit of tuning it could be shrunk to 5% or so.

In practice, I'd just let Celery run all the time. A single process waiting on an empty queue doesn't consume nearly any resources. It's also much more responsive and reliable.

Comment: But this mean basically starting and stopping workers continuously, independently of the number of tasks present in the queue, or?

Comment: The answer lets the worker die once the watched queue becomes empty.  Every two minutes, crontab starts a worker then "soft kills" it. The worker processes all remaining tasks then dies.  After two minutes, the worker starts again.